# GStreamer send 16 raw video over rtp

Tags: c++, stream, video-streaming, gstreamer, raw

I've a 16bit greyscale video stream from a LWIR (thermal camera) and I want to forward the stream over RTP without any compression.

gstreamer format is: video/x-raw,format=GRAY16_LE,width=640,height=520,framerate=9/1

But I can't find any plugin to transmit the data over RTP.
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtp/index.html?gi-language=c

Do you have an idea?

Thanks, Martin

Answer (score 0):

Check for the specs of uncompressed video data over RTP:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4175

As you will notice your specific format is not covered by the specification.